# Spring boot application deployed as web app in external tomcat doesn't write in log file

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I have a spring boot application which generates a WAR file for me. I deploy the WAR file to a Tomcat server running on Linux. I have setup my

> application.yml

like this:

```
logging:
        file: /var/log/tomcat/filereader1.log
        level:
            org.springframework: ERROR
            com.company: DEBUG
        pattern:
            file: '%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n'
            console: '%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:s
```

When I run the application (as a spring boot app with embedded tomcat) in my computer, I get a log file on the specified location, but when I deploy it on the Tomcat server I get no log file.

Is it because the way I am generating my WAR file? Or can it be because of filesystem permissions?

This is what I have tried

- I have tried putting in different directory.
- I have touched the file myself and chmoded it to 777 but still nothing.

this is my POM:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>file_reader</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>file_reader</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: It is because you are deploying to tomcat instead of using the embedded container. It will use the default logging of the Tomcat server instead of controlling its own logging.

Comment: is there a solution?